# Can I disable changing value of ion-range by touching line, and only for knobs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ion-range-slider

here's an example

[image: 1]

I need to make touchable knobs only, so touches on line won't affect on value ?

I tried make some changes in css to disable line like this

```
ion-range::part(bar) {
  display: none;
}
```

But that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to append an element to an ion-range parent div and with styles like z-index and position: relative and it worked for me, just overflowed with div possible space on the line except the knobs, added transparent color and working good

```
let elemOverflowDivForScroll = document.createElement('div');
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.position = 'relative';
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.zIndex = '999999999';
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.id = 'overflowDivForScroll'
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.height = '36px';
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.bottom = '36px';
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  elemOverflowDivForScroll.style.left = '5px'
```

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpAWj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfectly for me. Just add to css:

```
ion-range {
  pointer-events: none;
}

ion-range::part(knob) {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Seems to work on most browsers. Have a look here: https://caniuse.com/pointer-events